# get value of object key and parent javascript and create a new object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that looks like the following:

```js
const testObject = {
  "NameA": {
    "Name": {
      "_text": "Peter"
    }
  },
  "AgeA": {
    "_comment": "line=2",
    "age": {
      "_text": "21"
    }
  },
  "Birth": {
    "_comment": "line=3",
    "Birthday": {
      "DateTimeSignUTCOffset": {
        "Date": {
          "_text": "191201"
        },
        "Time": {
          "_text": "1123"
        },
      },
      "Test": {
        "Code": {
          "_text": "1234"
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to find any key with the key `_text` and get the corresponding value and the parent key.

i.e.

```
const result = { 
    "Name": "Peter",
    "age": "21",
    "Date": "191201",
    "Time": "1123",
    "Code": "1234"
};
```

I have tried the following by looping through the object but am unable to figure it out.

```
const result = {};

const find_items = (object) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(object));
  Object.keys(object).map((item) => {
    console.log(object[item]);
    if(object[item] !== '_text') {
      find_items(object[item])
    } else {
      console.log(item)
    }
  });
};

find_items(testObject);

console.log(result);
```

Can someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and check for object and if `_text` property exist take the value with the outer key or get the entries from the recursive call with the object.

At the end build an object from all entries.

```js
const
    flatEntries = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') return '_text' in v
                ? [[k, v._text]]
                : flatEntries(v);
            return [];        
        });
    testObject = { NameA: { Name: { _text: "Peter" } }, AgeA: { _comment: "line=2", age: { _text: "21" } }, Birth: { _comment: "line=3", Birthday: { DateTimeSignUTCOffset: { Date: { _text: "191201" }, Time: { _text: "1123" } }, Test: { Code: { _text: "1234" } } } } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(flatEntries(testObject));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

in English, what you want to do is:

create an empty object named "result", and then recursively iterate through the "object" object. each time you encounter a key linked to a sub-object which has a __text field, add that to the "result" object.

now just translate the above into JavaScript.

the keyword here is "recursively". your original code was not recursive.

Comment: but how would you get the parent key?

Comment: updated the question with the recursive function but still not working

Answer (score -1):

your idea is pretty good, but you want to find `_text` keys anywhere nested inside the object. To find inner, nested, keys, you need to recurse your function if the value of some key happens to be an object.

```
result = {}

find_text_keys = (haystack, label) => {
  Object.keys(ob).forEach(key => {
    if (key === '_text') {
      res[text] = ob["_text"];
    } else if (typeof(ob[key]) === "object") {
      find_text_keys(ob[key], key);
    }
  });
}
```

Then, calling the function with a default label `f(object, "default_label")` will populate the `result` dictionary as you desired.

Comment: does this work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).